Incremental deployment with Azure DevOps
I have multiple solution in Project. I need to deploy only those solution where the dev team has made changes.
First of all is it possible? If yes then how we can achieve it.
We create a build pipelines and a release pipeline and thought it will copy only updated files but it is copying all the artifacts.
We are expecting it should copy only updated dll's.

Hi @user26393142, Have you got a chance to check the answer below to use git diff command to get the changed solution? Hope the suggestion may help resolve your concern in this post.

Assuming you have a repo with the mulitple solutions in different paths like those in the image below;

Based on your requriment, you may run git diff command to know which path the change commit is pushed into, so as to determine whether to build those solutions or not.
Here is a sample YAML pipeline for your reference.
parameters:
- name: SLNs
  type: object
  default:
  - Solution1
  - Solution2

stages:
- stage: CI
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0 # Set fetchDepth as 0 to disable default shallowfetch and make sure git diff command works

    - ${{ each SLN in parameters.SLNs }}:
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "Build.SourceVersion is $(Build.SourceVersion)"

          # Check if there are changes in ${{SLN}}
          if (git diff --name-only $(Build.SourceVersion)^ $(Build.SourceVersion) -- ${{SLN}}) {
              Write-Host "Changes detected in ${{SLN}}"
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=build${{SLN}}]True"
          }
          else {
            Write-Host "No changes detected in ${{SLN}}"
          }
        displayName: 'Determine to Build ${{SLN}}'
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: 'build'
          projects: '${{SLN}}/*.sln'
          arguments: '-o:$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
        displayName: 'Build ${{SLN}}'
        condition: eq(variables['build${{SLN}}'], 'True')
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
        Contents: '*.dll'
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      displayName: Copy .dll files 
    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifact: drop

- stage: CD
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    environment: E-Test
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: |
              tree $(Pipeline.Workspace) /F /A
            displayName: Check artifacts


However, it may NOT be reliable if there are multiple commits under different paths within one single push. Therefore, it is still suggested creating seperate pipelines to be triggered by specific Paths filter and procceed to build and publish the solution in that path.
